# Is there something equivalent to Sonar for Perl?

Tags: perl, sonarqube

Is there something equivalent to [Sonar](http://sonar.codehaus.org/) for Perl ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Smolder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smolder) is a continuous integration framework that runs smoke tests and produces coverage reports, stats, and nice graphs. It accepts [TAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol) input, so anything that can provide this can be plugged in. You can use the various [TAP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?TAP) modules to provide integration on the Perl side.

You can also adapt off-the-shelf build systems. [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) and [BuildBot](http://buildbot.net/) can all be configured for Perl projects, although feature support will vary (Hudson is a little Java-centric). You can plug them together in different ways. For example, [TAP::Harness::JUnit](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?TAP::Harness::JUnit) produces JUnit-like output, which can be fed to your tools.

There's also the [Devel::Cover](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Cover) module which points out areas of untested code.

Here's an interesting [discussion](http://www.pjcj.net/testing_and_code_coverage/paper.html) of code coverage in Perl.

Comment: A small correction: Smolder doesn't actually run your tests (you set that up on your own), but it's really pretty easy to setup.

Answer (score 3):

For code analysis, you can use [PerlCritic](http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/Perl-Critic-1.122/lib/Perl/Critic.pm)