# How to handle code coverage of both Perl scripts and modules?

Tags: perl, code-coverage

I have a unique requirement of handling code coverage of my Perl scripts.

I have written a few Perl scripts which in turn uses a few Perl modules. My requirement is to use run these Perl scripts with different options they support and assess the code coverage of both Perl scripts and Perl modules.

So I am using `Devel::Cover`, `Module::Build` and `Test::More` from CPAN. It's all woring fine if I call functions inside Perl modules directly inside test script. But it's not working if I call the scripts directly (In this case I am not getting generated with code coverage of Perl modules and scripts both).

Here is my example test script using Test::More:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More; 

BEGIN { plan tests => 1 }

ok(sub {
   my @args = ("ex4200fw","-query-fw","-i","192.168.168.1");
   #print "# Executing @args \n";
   `@args`;
   my $rc = $? >> 8;
   #print "# Return code: $rc \n";
   $rc == 1
}->(),"Query Juniper EX4200 FW, incorrect IP address.\n");
```

Here `ex4200fw` (is in path) is the Perl script written by me which in turn calls dependent module `updates.pm`.

- Do we have any tools to suite to this requirement?
- Running Perl scripts and getting code coverage of both scripts and its dependent modules?
- Can we accomplish the same using above CPAN modules?

Any sample script is much useful for me.

Comment: A couple of other questions you will probably find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423491/is-there-something-equivalent-to-sonar-for-perl/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230065/what-are-some-code-coverage-tools-for-perl

Answer (score 5):

### Gathering coverage statistics

To gather coverage statistics you need to `use Devel::Cover`. (If you can't directly change the source core of included scripts you can just specify `-MDevel::Cover` as a parameter to perl.)

So you should rather change your "test script" to add this parameter when calling other Perl script like following:

```
my @args = ("perl", "-MDevel::Cover", "ex4200fw","-query-fw","-i","192.168.168.1");
```

Or you can specify enviroment variable `PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover` before top test script is executed. In this case you'll not need to change any script source. Here is a small shell sample:

```
## run tests and gather coverage statistics
export PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover
perl test1.pl
perl test2.pl
...
```

### Calculate result coverage

There is the [`cover`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Cover) utility which outputs all lines which were executed. You should run it after all tests are executed. Standard modules are excluded from the report by default.